# ng-change not firing even with valid ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input type="text" class="text-input" ng-model="dashboard_settings.settings.currentPassword" ng-change="dashboard.verifyPassword(dashboard_settings.settings.currentPassword);" ng-model-options="{debounce:1000}">
```

I have a very simple input, shown above. ng-change is not getting fired even though the element has a model. Why could this be happening?

Comment: Where's the code? We have no way to verify this issue. See [mcve]

Comment: It's part of a big project I'm working on. Give me a second and I'll create a plunk.

Comment: Does the function `dashboard.verifyPassword(dashboard_settings.settings.currentPassword);` exist, is it in scope and spelt right?

Comment: Looks fine almost exactly the same as the example Angular gives: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange#example
And that plunker works
Check your call to the `verifyPassword` function in your controller and see if it works

Comment: Better way to debug (and clean your html) is to call a function on the controller such as `verifyPassword()` and in that `verifyPassword` function you can call the `dashboard.verifyPassword`. This way you can set breakpoints and inspect.

Comment: Somehow I only typed `dashboard` and not `dashboard_settings`. It's late and I have been staring at this code for way long that I didn't notice it. Thanks for the help though :-)!.

Comment: try change your model to this `ng-model="dashboard.dashboard_settings.settings.currentPassword"`